# Explain the logic

Tags: c, logical-operators, logical-or

```
  #include <stdio.h>
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

 int main(void)
 {
    int i=10, j=2, k=0, m;
    m=++i || ++j && ++k;
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d",i,j,k,m);
 }
```

> can anyone explain the logic, Output is 11,2,0,1

Comment: Have you tried going through it on paper? Do you know about "short-circuit evaluation"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: @Caleb not at all, everything here is sequenced and well-defined.

Comment: @Caleb This code is well-defined and there is no issue with UB or sequence points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i starts as 10, but is incremented to 11, before it is tested.

m is being assigned a boolean result, so will be either 0 or 1.

i is non zero so evaluates to true for a boolean expression, therefore, the expression after the || do not need to be evaluated, as || is a boolean short circuit evaluator.

Hence your output.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the priorities of operations this expression statement

```
m=++i || ++j && ++k;
```

is equivalent to

```
m = ++i || ( ++j && ++k );
```

You can imagine it like

```
m = expression1 || expression2;
```

where `expression1` is `++i` and `expression2` is `( ++j && ++k )`

According to the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated**.

As `expression1` compares unequal to 0 (its value is equal to 11) then `expression2` is not evaluated.

Thus only `expression1` is evaluated and it is unequal to 0.

According to another quote from the same section of the C Standard

> 3 The || operator **shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0**; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

The result of the evaluation of the right side is equal to 1 that is assigned to the variable `m`.

Thus only the variable `i` and `m` were changed. The variables `j` and `k` were not changed because the expression where they are present as operands was not evaluated.